# Formula to calculate the combination of two patterns

Tags: combinations

Is their a formula to calculate the combination of two patterns?:
Lets say I have rows of lightbulbs, a pattern representes the space between two turned-on lightbulbs.
Easier to explain with an example:

```
Pattern 1: 4, 3
Pattern 2: 3
```

The meaning of the patterns:

```
lightbulb on: |
lightbulb off: -

Pattern 1: |---|--|---|--|---|--|---|--|---|--|---|--|---|--|---|--|---|--|
Pattern 2: |--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|

Combined : |-----------------|--|-----------------|--|-----------------|--|
New Combined Pattern: 18, 3
```

Comment: Well, for starters... if the sum of the spacings in the first pattern is $a$ and the sum of the spacings in the second pattern is $b$, then you only need to consider the first $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ positions since it will repeat.  As for specifically what happens within that range... well... that would depend largely on what specific patterns you have.

Comment: @JMoravitz Isn't there a formula to find the combined positions within 'that' range?

Comment: Multiple repeated applications of chinese remainder theorem?  Doesn't really seem worth it to me